# PHP insert query not inserting all the content from xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to insert the data from the xml where i have 300+ plus rows but my query inserting only 59 - 60 rows. Kindly help to me sort the issue.

In the below XML, I have removed all the details and just described the sample layout.

Actual XML layout file looks like below

```
<Listings>
<Listing>
<Ad_Type>Rent</Ad_Type>
<Unit_Type>Apartment</Unit_Type>
<Unit_Builtup_Area>938.00</Unit_Builtup_Area>
<No_of_Bathroom>2</No_of_Bathroom>
<Price>75000</Price>
<Frequency>per year</Frequency>
</Listing>

<Listing>
 ......
</Listing>
<Listing>
 ......
</Listing>
<Listing>
 ......
</Listing>
  <Listing>
   ......
  </Listing>
</Listings>
```

My PHP query

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "xxxx");

$affectedRow = 0;
echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();

//$xml = simplexml_load_file("my xml file url here") or die("Error: Cannot create object");


foreach ($xml->children() as $row) {

    $price = $row->Price;
    $Bathroom = $row->No_of_Bathroom;
    $Ad_Type = $row->Ad_Type;
    $Unit_Type = $row->Unit_Type;
    $Unit_Builtup_Area = $row->Unit_Builtup_Area;
    $ref = $row->Property_Ref_No;
    $frequency = $row->Frequency

    $sql = "INSERT INTO properties(price, Bathroom, Ad_Type, Unit_Type, Unit_Builtup_Area, ref_no, frequency) VALUES (

    '" . $price. "',
    '" . $Bathroom. "',
    '" . $Ad_Type. "',
    '" . $Unit_Type. "',
    '" . $Unit_Builtup_Area. "',
    '" . $frequency. "',
    '" . $ref. "'
    )";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (! empty($result)) {
        $affectedRow ++;
        echo 'Rows created '.$affectedRow.'<br>';
    } else {
        $error_message = mysqli_error($conn) . "\n";
    }
}
?>
<h2>Insert XML Data to MySql Table Output</h2>
<?php echo $affectedRow ?>
<?php
if ($affectedRow > 0) {
    $message = $affectedRow . " records inserted";
} else {
    $message = "No records inserted";
}

?>
```

I have 300 plus listings in the xml but the query inserting only 60 rows. I am expecting the query to insert all the rows from the XML.

Comment: Is there anything in the $error_message? Pls determine if the error is in the php code or in mysql.

Comment: @Shadow. No. there is no error in the php code.

Comment: Then there must be something in the $error_message.

Comment: set_time_limit(0) ? Otherwise enable debugging mode in PHP ini_set(‘display_errors’. 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); to see what is going wrong possibly

Comment: Thank you  @Shadow and Raymond Nijland. I echoed the $error_message, there was an error because of single quotes in one of the fields in XML caused an error. I added `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Now its worked as expected.